# Javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript

I am using the `magicSuggest` multi select filter in this i want to call the api method through the ajax call and i also need to pass the parameter to ajax call through the `magicSuggest plugin`.
code:

```
tagNamesuggestFilter = $('#srcTagNameID').magicSuggest({
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    data: 'http://localhost:55498/api/note/' + refID + '/tags?noteTypeID=' + 1,
    dataUrlParams: { "commenterRoleIDs": commenterList },
    valueField: 'TagID',
    displayField: 'TagName'
});
```

thanks

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: You should also describe your problem and tell the community what you have already tried to achieve.

Comment: my problem is  i want to pass the parameter using dataUrlParams in magicSuggest plugin and need to call the web service.